# Django Rest Framework Token User with MongoEngine User

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

i try to get token using Django Rest Framework but doesn't accept my user

```
'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'model'
```

models

```
class User(Document):
first_name = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
last_name = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
email = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
password = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)

def set_password(self,password):
    self.password = make_password(password)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'User'
```

view

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    email = request.data['user'].get("email")
    password = request.data['user'].get("password")

    usert = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if not usert:
        return Response({"error": usert}, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data['user'])
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']

    token, created  = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({"token": token})
```

Please let me know how I can get this to work.

Comment: that can't be your entire view.

Comment: @Jason what do you mean ?

Comment: post your entire view method.  and what is `Token`?  You're leaving a great deal of information out of your question

Comment: it's ok now @Jason

Comment: I think the problem is that your User class is not inherited from authuser in django.

Comment: i use mongodb i think it's necessary to put Document @MenglongLi

Comment: Did you define AUTH_USER_MODEL = "xxx" in your settings?

Comment: @MenglongLi I can't because i use mongodb i think must to use User(document )